# Converting pickle files to csv gives regular UnicodeEncodeErrors

Tags: python, csv, unicode, python-3.6, pickle

I downloaded the Reuters-full-data-set and generated pkl files. Using a script ('dump_to_csv.py') in Windows 10 command prompt to convert the pkl files to csv works up to a point, but every now and then (too many times for comfort), it will throw an error, now the code I'm using (from a GitHub repository) was updated to fix errors in Python 3, however the errors still occur (for me at least). Using Python 3.6.4 in Windows 10-Pro (64-bit).
The code for the 'dump_to_csv.py' file is located here https://github.com/philipperemy/Reuters-full-data-set/blob/master/dump_to_csv.py

The errors are all very similar i.e.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dump_to_csv.py", line 41, in <module>
    read(sys.argv[1])
  File "dump_to_csv.py", line 34, in read
    w.write(line)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 31-47: character maps to <undefined>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1) I wonder if these files were created by python2.7 or earlier as python3 pickle format are not compatible with each other 2) are you sure to use `latin1` encoding instead of UTF-8?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I checked with the original Reuters source and it seems to be Japanese characters which are the problem - so I need to ask a separate question regarding this now.

Comment: Could you try to load the same pickle files with Python2? As I've said, formats for Python2 and Python3 are different and incompatible with each other.

Comment: I tried that,  I get this:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dump_to_csv.py", line 41, in <module>
    read(sys.argv[1])
  File "dump_to_csv.py", line 15, in read
    u = pickle._Unpickler(f)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_Unpickler' `

So not sure what it means.. but presumably as I generated the pickle files with Python 3 it means there's a compatibility issue.

Comment: You need to use `Unpickler` class, not `_Unpickler`.

Comment: Why, would that help?

Comment: You shouldn't use private attributes directly

Comment: ok thanks - still not working though. What to do next? Bear in mind I'm a python newbie..